# Fetch Nested loop array fetch from api in react, redux

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, nested-loops

I need to fetch all the results as table from the api. I wonder How to do nested array 'results[i]' .  You can see from the picture that I fetch only one results, Because of 'results[0]'.  Could Anybody suggestions me to fetch 
 all the results in a table?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchData } from '../actions/index';

class DataList extends Component {
componentWillMount() {
this.props.fetchData();
}

render() {
const dataItems = this.props.table.map(data => (
  <tr key={data.results[0].id}>
    <td>{data.results[0].id}</td>
    <td>
      <img
        style={{ width: '150px', height: '100px' }}
        src={data.results[0].image}
      />
    </td>
    <td>{data.results[0].name}</td>
    <td>{data.results[0].status}</td>
    <td>{data.results[0].species}</td>
  </tr>
));

return (
  <table className="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Character image</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Species</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>{dataItems}</tbody>
   </table>
 );
}
}

 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  table: state.table
 });

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchData })(DataList);
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You could also read why images of code is not the best idea [here](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I updated my question. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Fez Vrasta Could you help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you should map over results not a table

```
const dataItems = this.props.table.map(data => (
<tr key={data.results[0].id}>
<td>{data.results[0].id}</td>
<td>
  <img
    style={{ width: '150px', height: '100px' }}
    src={data.results[0].image}
  />
</td>
<td>{data.results[0].name}</td>
<td>{data.results[0].status}</td>
<td>{data.results[0].species}</td>
</tr>
```

));

should be

```
const dataItems = this.props.table.results.map(result => (
<tr key={result.id}>
<td>{result.id}</td>
<td>
  <img
    style={{ width: '150px', height: '100px' }}
    src={result.image}
  />
</td>
<td>{result.name}</td>
<td>{result.status}</td>
<td>{result.species}</td>
</tr>
```

));

and then it will work, you could've also passed through connect only results not "table" like you call it

Comment: Hi @AlexGvozden,  Thanks for your response. I did as you said and got this error.  bundle.js:23601 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined
    at DataList.render (bundle.js:23601)

Comment: After I map through the results I still couldn't get all the data. If I put results[0] then I could get one row.         ```   render() {
      const dataItems = this.props.results.map(data => (
        <tr key={data.results[0].id}>
        <td>{data.results[0].id}</td>
        <td>
          <img
            style={{ width: '150px', height: '100px' }}
            src={data.results[0].image}
          />
        </td>
        <td>{data.results[0].name}</td>
        <td>{data.results[0].status}</td>
        <td>{data.results[0].species}</td>
      </tr>
       ));
         ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. Problem was with the nested loop.

```
render() {

const dataItems = this.props.results.map(result =>

(result.results.map(item =>

(

<tr key={item.id}>

<td>{item.id}</td>

<td>

<img

style={{ width: '150px', height: '100px' }}

src={item.image}

/>

</td>

<td>{item.name}</td>

<td>{item.status}</td>

<td>{item.species}</td>

</tr>

)
```